# How do I read the audio output on my PC in Python?

Tags: python, audio

I would like to make a spectrum analyzer which listens not to a microphone, but to the sound being output by the PC. For example, I would be able to open the analyzer alongside YouTube, start the analyzer, then start a video in YouTube. The analyzer would display the spectrums of the YouTube video. How would this be done?

I have looked at several examples of how to make a spectrum analyzer which analyzes a mic input, but I have not managed to find anything which can read the PC's output audio.

Windows 10 Home
Python 3.7.5 installed under Visual Studio 2019

Comment: I'd suggest installing something like [VB-CABLE](https://www.vb-audio.com/Cable/index.htm) which will give you a virtual audio device that you can read from like a regular microphone.

Comment: @Michael Mior, thank you for that suggestion! I will look into that.

Comment: [Do any of these help?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%5Baudio%5D+output)

Comment: No, I had previously looked at several of those. I think the VB-Cable solution is my ticket in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

The standard _portaudio.pyd module can't allow to read the output audio stream. Instead, a portaudio module with loopback WASapi should be developed.
You can see the project (block diagram) in the image
[image: 10BarsSpectrumAnalyzerWithWASapi.jpg]

Of course, reading the PC output audio stream the spectrum of any sound played through headphones / speakers will be displayed. The audio source (Media Player, Web browser, etc is irrelevant)

I designed and made a whole 10 led bar spectrum analyzer by Python. Instead to use the nunmpy library (too big and useless to get just the FFT) a python pyd module (just 27KB) to get the FFT and to split the entire audio spectrum to bands was created.

In addition, to read the output audio a loopback WASapi portaudio pyd module was created. You can see the project (block diagram) in the image [image: same image]

Just added a tutorial video on my YouTube channel: [how to design and make a very smart Python Spectrum Analyzer 10 Led Bar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Otqdwql63c)